# Cannot get hidden column value in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to get all the value of all of a hidden datatable column.

The column that is hidden has a class name `plantID`. So to get all of the values in an array I was doing:

```
let plantID=  $('#tblMain .plantID').map(function() {
        return $(this).html()
}).get()
```

This was working just fine before I decided to hide the column:

```
let tblMain = $('#tblMain').DataTable({

    "pageLength": 10,
    columnDefs: [{
        "targets":[4],
        "searchable": false,
        "visible":false
    }]

  });
```

Now `plantID` returns nothing.

I was inserting the value into the column using jquery:

```
$(this).parent().find('.plantID').html(plantValue)
```

I did some research and based on some other replies on Stack Overflow I also tried doing:

```
  let cell = tblMain.cell($(this))
  cell.data(plantValue).draw()
```

This method also only works if the column is not hidden. If the column is hidden, I cannot retrieve the values of the `plantID` column.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the column data via DataTables itself using [`column().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()), I've worked up a simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tbgn9hqf/ where clicking the button grabs all the data from the hidden `ID` column, hope that helps.

```
$("#getIds").on("click", function(){
    alert('Hidden column sum: ' + table.column(0).data().reduce((a, b) =>  ~~a + ~~b ));
});
```